# VS Code, click to follow a file and line

Tags: terminal, hyperlink, visual-studio-code

Let's say I have a GCC compilation output in the internal terminal with a line like this:

> /a/path/to/a/file.h:95: undefined reference to ...

the file is a link which is allowed to perform Ctrl + click to follow. It just jumps at the beginning of the file.

My question is then, is it possible to make it take the line number into the account? So instead of jumping to the beginning of the file, it would jump to line 95.